# How to put custom content in collapsed ExtJS panel bar?

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel

I have a Panel in my application that collapses to the left side of the screen. What I'd like to do is add some custom content, like icons, to the vertical bar that represents the collapsed panel. A good example would be what Outlook does when you collapse the Mail pane:

[image: collapsed mail pane]

Is there built-in support for this in ExtJS? If not, what would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for a vertical toolbar in ExtJS 4.0 . Example [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/toolbar/vertical-toolbars.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to hide the panel and replace it with a previously hidden panel that is the width you want the collapsed panel to be to support all the objects, as the objects are natively going to be supported in the title region.

Frankly this is what outlook is doing as well.

Comment: Good call, I'll probably end up hiding the collapsed panel but then replacing it with a vertical toolbar as Swar mentioned. Thanks for your help!